# Manga where the female lead is reborn years later

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I remember that she kills the king with a sword dance and I think she had red hair.

Comment: Welcome to Sci Fi & Fantasy Stack Exchange. Please read https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/4918 https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/4918 our guides for how to ask a good identification question.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Once you've read the above links, please [edit] in the extra details, and then we can reopen your question to answers. Thanks again!

Comment: @b_jonas - I feel like this one was closed unfairly. I count 7 separate piece of info that would be very unlikely to be together (manga / female lead / reborn / reborn many years later / kills someone / kills a king / sword dance). The 'sword dance' in particular is going to be highly identifiable

Comment: @Valorum Some of those 7 are guaranteed to be together: if someone is "reborn many years later", they're definitely "reborn", and if a character "kills a king", then that's definitely a tick for "kills someone" too. The first two pieces of information "manga" and "female lead" also don't seem like they narrow anything down much.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Someone who's reborn has to be many years later? That doesn't seem right. They could be reborn at the instant of their death or reincarnated in the past

Comment: Female MC means we've already narrowed it down by about 80%

Comment: I didn't even notice the red hair. Now we know it's in colour (or at least has a colour cover)

Comment: @Valorum I think you need to reread my comment, you got it the wrong way round.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am very sure this is [The Lady and the Beast](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-lady-and-the-beast).

This is only the beginning of the story (first two to three chapters), but everything matches (red haired female protagonist that kills a king with a sword dance and is reborn - with red hair again - 100 years after her death).

The story revolves around her taking her sister's place in an arranged marriage with a duke, that was turned into a beast (huge wolf) by a hereditary curse, and her breaking the curse.